# Concurrent Producers block indefinitely in Rabbitmq

Tags: java, performance, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-rabbit

I am observing strange behavior while doing a POC of Rabbitmq 3.3.5 using spring-rabbit-1.3.9.RELEASE library

When I start a single producing thread, things run smoothly. But if start more than 1 thread concurrently, only one of them ever finishes, all others get blocked indefinitely, even after the queue becomes empty.

The status of the blocked threads' connections remains running, when monitored from `rabbitmqctl list_connections`. It should be noted that there are no alarms when producers block, or at any other time during the complete run.

I have also observed that the issue disappears if I put a sleep of 1 millisecond after each send.

So, I have these questions

1. Does rabbitmq not support concurrent producers, publishing at high rates?
2. Even if connections are indeed blocked, why doesn't it show in rabbitmqctl list_connections?
3. Why do they block indefinitely and not recover whey queue becomes empty?

Code

```
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
        init();
        PocConfig config = new PocConfig();
        int threadCount = config.getThreadCount();
        final int eventsPerThread = config.getEvents() / threadCount;
        final long sleep = config.getSleep();

        System.out.println("Start producer with configuration [threadCount=" + threadCount + ", events=" + eventsPerThread + ", sleep="
            + sleep + "]");

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            final int threadId = i;
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    produce(eventsPerThread, sleep, threadId);
                }
            });
        }
        waitAndTearDown(executorService);
    }

    private static void produce(int events, long sleep, int threadId)     {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int index = 1; index <= events; index++) {
            try {
                byte[] message = messageFactory.createTestMessage(index);
                amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, message);
                if (sleep > 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error", e);
            }
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Producer:" + threadId + " finished, events: " + events + ", Time(s): " + time / 1000 + ", tps: " + (events * 1000) / time);
    }
```

Spring configuration

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="addresses" value="${addresses}" />
    <property name="username" value="${user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${passwd}" />
    <property name="cacheMode" value="CONNECTION" />
    <property name="connectionCacheSize" value="${threads}" />
    <property name="channelCacheSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<rabbit:template id="template" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="testExchange" routing-key="testQueue"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing I can think of that would block, so I just ran your test; and had  no problems:

```
Start producer with configuration [threadCount=5, events=10, sleep=0]
Producer:2 finished, events: 1000, Time(s): 0, tps: 4405
Producer:3 finished, events: 1000, Time(s): 0, tps: 4132
Producer:1 finished, events: 1000, Time(s): 0, tps: 4048
Producer:0 finished, events: 1000, Time(s): 0, tps: 3968
Producer:4 finished, events: 1000, Time(s): 0, tps: 3952
```

What makes you think they're blocked?

Take a thread dump (e.g. with jstack) to see what the threads are doing.

**EDIT**:

I still can't reproduce it, even with 1M messages and `CacheMode CONNECTION`...

```
Start producer with configuration [threadCount=5, events=200000, sleep=0]
Producer:0 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 50, tps: 3959
Producer:3 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 53, tps: 3746
Producer:1 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 55, tps: 3635
Producer:2 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 55, tps: 3634
Producer:4 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 55, tps: 3629
```

I **do** see the queue goes into `flow` mode (via the admin UI) but everything recovers just fine.

I do see your worker is under flow control...

```
"pool-2-thread-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4af4849800 nid=0x65d5 runnable [0x00007f4ae082f000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
```

Do you see anything in the rabbit log? What do you see on the admin UI regarding messsage rates, status etc?

Regardless, this does not appear to have anything to do with Spring AMQP; you will need to contact the rabbitmq guys on the `rabbitmq-users` google group.

(I was testing with rabbitmq 3.4.2).

**EDIT2:**

With a completely clean install of 3.5.2...

```
Start producer with configuration [threadCount=5, events=200000, sleep=0]
Producer:0 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 39, tps: 5091
Producer:1 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 39, tps: 5002
Producer:2 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 40, tps: 4954
Producer:3 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 40, tps: 4951
Producer:4 finished, events: 200000, Time(s): 40, tps: 4939
```

and I saw no `flow` state in the admin UI (on the queue, but the channels/connections show they were in flow, but again recovered).

Comment: I am testing with a million events, anyway, here's the essential parts of thread dump http://pastebin.com/0B035D0j  I know they are stuck, because they don't print finish message, as well as the message count on rabbit does not increase after one thread finishes. Here's the sample log http://pastebin.com/37rk8bYp

Comment: Gary, are you testing with rabbit on localhost? I am only seeing this when hitting rabbitmq on another machine in the cluster, and not on localhost. Regarding flow mode, yes I see one connection going in flow mode and then recovering, but all other connections remain running always.

Comment: Gary, the problem seems to be with ConnectionFactory, as things run fine if I start 5 separate processes with 1 thread each, or if I have separate connection factory for each thread in a single process.

Comment: It works fine for me over the LAN to a 3.5.3 cluster. I don't see how it can be the connection factory; in your thread dump, the threads are clearly waiting on the socket write in the underlying connection so the connection factory clearly served up a connection ok.

Comment: Yes I agree, it shouldn't be...but quite strangely having separate factories seems to fix it. Of course it all doesn't make sense, and you can't replicate it, so I have to validate it from other sources. Is there any way to see why threads might be stuck on socket connection, rabbitmq logs contain nothing of help. Also, moving to 3.5.3 didn't change anything for me.

Comment: I am happy to help you debug this weird situation (if I can reproduce it locally). Do you have any unusual/complex configuration broker-side? I am testing with a simple queue bound to a direct exchange. I have 10 consumers draining the queue. While I *do* see flow control kicking in, everything recovers fine and all producers complete and all the messages are consumed.

Comment: Well, the problem is occurring when rabbitmq box is in a different aws availability zone then the client. The issue seems to be network glitches/high latency between these zones. The client apparently behaves as if the tcp network interface is down, and blocks until the OS timeouts the connection. We have not changed the default broker settings, and the queue topology is exactly the same. The flow control actually doesn't kick in, indeed server has not a whim of the client blockage and displays connections as running.

Comment: Perhaps increase the heartbeat frequency?

Comment: Yes reducing the heartbeat to very low value like 5 secs improves things, so writes block upto maximum of heartbeat interval, after which server closes the connection. But still it doesn't explain why the problem happens exclusively when sharing CachingConnectionFactory with multiple threads and not when using vanilla rabbit java client.